# Getting a String from a list separated by a comma

Tags: java

String s = name1, name2, name3, name4

How would I extract name2, name3, and name4 from the String.

I know I have to use s.split(",") , but I am not sure how to code a loop that would ignore name1

Comment: you don't need a loop for this

Comment: did I answered your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@user3437460 has the correct answer but if you were specifically looking to use a loop you just need to start at index 1 to ignore the first token.

```
String[] tokens = input.split(",");

for (int i = 1; i < tokens.length; i++) {
   // do something with tokens[i]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't really have to explicitly ignore it. If you tokenized the string, you can just ignore the first token by not using it.

Let me give you an example.

```
    String[]str= s.split(",");
    String name1 = str[0]; //Just ignore this
    String name2 = str[1];
    String name3 = str[2];
    String name4 = str[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

After splitting, check the length of array and if contains more than 1 element, then read element at index 1 for `name2`.

**Example**":

```
String s = "name1, name2, name3, name4";

String [] names = s.split( "," );

String name2 = null;
if( names.length() > 1 ) {
  name2 = names[ 1 ];
}

System.out.println( name2 );
```

And to read further you can use other indexes on other names.

```
String name3 = names[ 2 ];
String name4 = names[ 3 ];
```